# How send a custom mail using android studio?

Tags: java, android, email, jakarta-mail

im trying to send mails using the javamail api from my app, it works perfectly but i want to customize the mail. Because with this code just send de body of my form, but i would like to receive the Name and Mail from the user who send it.

```
public synchronized void sendMail(String Mail, String Nombre, String Correo, String Asunto, String sender, String Texto, String email) throws Exception {
        try{
            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage (session);
            DataHandler handler = new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(Texto.getBytes(), "text/plain"));
            message.setSender(new InternetAddress(sender));
            message.setSubject(Asunto);
            message.setDataHandler(handler);
            if (email.indexOf(',') > 0)
                message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(email));
            else
                message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(email));
            Transport.send(message);
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("Error", "sendingMailError"+ e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

there is an option to add it with using Mimemessage? or should use an other one?

Thanks